# got Uncaught TypeError in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="divTest1">hi</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function DocumentReady(event)
{
       console.log(event.type); 
}

$('#divTest1').click(DocumentReady(event));
</script>
```

Question:

In chrome->console, it shows:`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` , so what is going wrong with the above codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `DocumentReady` and passing its result as the callback for `$('#divTest1').click`.

Just pass the function:

```
$('#divTest1').click(DocumentReady);
```

Comment: thanks, your solution is right. But can u explain: why it shows `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`?

Comment: @user2294256: Because `event` is `undefined`.

Comment: so for `$('#divTest1').click(DocumentReady(event));`, parameter `event` is not the `click` event, but for `function DocumentReady(event)`,  parameter `event` is the `click` event, why?

Comment: @user2294256: What do you think `DocumentReady(event)` does?

Comment: this is my thought:`DocumentReady(event)` is the reference of `function DocumentReady(event)`,

Comment: @user2294256: `DocumentReady(event)` calls `DocumentReady` with the variable `event` as its first argument.