# how to see the contents inside ready() event in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="divTest1"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function DocumentReady(e)
{
        $("#divTest1").text("Hello, world!");  console.log(e);
}

$(document).ready(DocumentReady);
</script>
```

In chrome->console, it shows:`function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)}`

Questions:

1. what does this mean: `function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)}`?
2. actually i want to see the contents(e.g.type...) inside event`:ready()`, how could I do this?

Comment: 1. It means that `e` is a function. 2. What contents?

Comment: Any relation with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518113/got-uncaught-typeerror-in-jquery/17518122#17518122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no actual "ready" event, so you can't inspect it. `$(document).ready(handler)` does not pass the handler an event object; it passes the handler the jQuery object `$`. The console output you're seeing is the string representation of the jQuery object, roughly corresponding to its source code.

Answer (score 0):

*user2357112 answered your first question about the function code nicely with:*

> There is no actual "ready" event, so you can't inspect it.
>   $(document).ready(handler) does not pass the handler an event object;
>   it passes the handler the jQuery object $. The console output you're
>   seeing is the string representation of the jQuery object, roughly
>   corresponding to its source code.

*Here's my answer to your second question, to get info about that "e" variable:*

The key here is to set a debug breakpoint.

If you go to the sources tab in Chrome's developer tools, there is a left hand column (might be on the far left, under the menu as little square icon with an arrow inside.

Find the HTML document that this code appears within. Try this if you can't find it:

- Within the tab menu that appears there, click "Sources".
- Find the item in the list named "(program)"
- The code on the page should appear to the right

You can then set a debug breakpoint by double clicking on the row number next to $("#divTest1") etc.

Now, once you refresh the page, the code will stop at that point, and in the right hand site, under "Scope Variables", "Local", you can expand the "e" variable, and get a whole lot of info on the event variable.

You don't have to print variables to the console.

Answer (score 0):

First on this part `$(document).ready( DocumentReady() )` you nee to execute the function as soon the DOM is ready to be manipulated. on your function you are expecting an event?, if inside of the function you execute a simple console.log( 'here on the docreadyfunction') you can see tha on the console.

```
function DocumentReady(e)
```